# How to Solve Django rest-framework JSON parse Error

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

What is wrong with this JSON?
when trying to send a POST request with POSTMAN getting JSON PARSE ERROR.

Error from Postman

```
{
  "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 5 column 13 (char 82)"
}
```

JSON Data sending From Postman

```
{
"menu_name": "indian_menu",
"slug": "indianmenu",
"item_name": [
    "category": "indianmenu",
  ]
}
```

rest_framework Serializers

```
class MenuCardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
    model = MenuCard
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ('menu_name', )

class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

category = MenuCardSerializer(required=True, many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Menu
    fields = '__all__'

  def create(self, validated_data):
    category = validated_data.pop('category')
    menu = MenuCard.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for choice in category:
        Menu.objects.create(**choice, category=menu)
```

rest_framework API_VIEWS

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', ])
def simple_menu(request, slug):

print("simple menu slug : " + slug)

if request.method == 'GET':
    category_list = Menu.objects.all()
    serializer = MenuSerializer(category_list)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = MenuSerializer(data=request.data, many=False)
    data = {}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        data["success"] = "item Catagory Created"
        return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: The error possibly comes from `"item_name": [ "category": "indian_menu"]`. You probably wanted to create a `dict`, but it is a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You JSON from postman is not a valid one, you can easily check it with any JSON validator.

In your first example it should be a dict not list as oz19 mentioned.
The same problem in the second one, the correct one is something like this:

```
{ 
   "menu_name":"Indian Menu",
   "slug":"indianmenu",
   "item_name":[ 
      { 
         "category":"Indian Menu",
         "item_name":"dal",
         "price":"22.30",
         "stock":"10"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: error bro {
    "item_name": [
        "Not a valid string."
    ],
    "price": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "stock": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}

Comment: It says invalid string why

Answer (score 0):

The error possibly comes from the data you are entering on Postman. On `item_name` you probably wanted to create a `dict`, but it is a `list`.

Change:

```
{
  ...
  "item_name": [ "category": "indian_menu"]
}
```

By:

```
{
  ...
  "item_name": { "category": "indian_menu" }
}
```

Comment: {
  ...
  "item_name": { "category": "indian_menu" }
} showing the fields are required.